Console outputs the following line incorrectly
.NET 8
I have a Middleware that reads the request response:
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

    using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
    {
        context.Response.Body = responseBody;

        await _next(context);

        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var responseText = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Console.WriteLine("Response Body:");
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);

        await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
    }
}

And I made a test controller, which is similar in functionality to the real case:
[HttpGet("sample")]
public IActionResult GetSample()
{
    var s = "[\r\n {    \"id\": \"test\",\r\n \"id\": \"test\"   } ]";
    return Content(s, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
}

This controller returns the correct result:

But when I use the following line, I get an incorrect response:
[HttpGet("sample")]
public IActionResult GetSample()
{
    var s = "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"id\": \"test\",\r\n        \"tt\": \"213\",\r\n        \"nn\": \"33\"\r\n    }\r\n]";
    return Content(s, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
}


The response is displayed correctly in Postman


This could very likely be an encoding problem (is the console you're writing configured to use UTF-8?). Attach a debugger and inspect the value of responseText

I create an asp.net core mvc project to test your code, but everything works well. So, there may be some issue out of the code you provided, If the issue has not been solved, could you kindly provide me a sample demo that can reproduce this issue?

Thank you all for the feedback!
I solved the problem by deleting a line from Program.cs:
app.UseResponseCompression();


i think there is issue with your text encoding.
add this into program.cs :
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
by the way why don't simply use this way :
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Test()
 {
     var arrayResult = new[] { new { a = 1, result = "result" } };
     return Ok(arrayResult);
 }

or
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Test()
 {
     var objectResult = new { a = 1, result = "result" };
     return Content(JsonSerializer.Serialize(objectResult));
 }

